# How to use email service tasks in JBPM6

Tags: jbpm

I am newbie to the JBPM6 and currently I am studying on the BPM notations.  I have a problem in adding how to apply an email notification to the process when a user task is done (if one user task is completed then send notification to the next level).  Because I couldn’t find a useful documents regarding that (eg: Send Tasks, Receive Tasks, message events, email service etc.)  Appreciate very much if anyone can help me with this with a proper example. (like how to add data input set, output set etc.)
And also please help me with how to add business rule tasks to a process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through domain specific services ?

See [JBPM manual Domain Specific Tasks](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html).

Domain specific task is a key extension point in jBPM where we can add new task types to jBPM. The documentation is exemplified, using a notification example. might be usefull to you.